# Overriding/Overlaying a XUL method

Tags: firefox-addon

I want to change behavior of Firefox on drag and drop action (for fixing this [WONTFIX bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=673157) and applying this a bit old [patch](https://bug673157.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=549540) with my addon). How I can override [this](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/browser/base/content/tabbrowser.xml#1847) method through XUL overlaying? I tried some codes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE override SYSTEM "chrome://dragdrop/locale/overlay.dtd">
<overlay id="ondrop-overlay"
         xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"> 

      <binding id="tabbrowser">
          <implementation>
              <method name="onDrop">
                <body>
                ...
                </body>
              </method>
          </implementation>
      </binding>

</overlay>
```

While

```
overlay chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml chrome://dragdrop/content/tabbrowser.xul
```

was in my chrome.manifest,
but I had not any success. Please help me, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overlays only apply to XUL documents, not to XBL bindings (it is a XUL feature and not supported by XBL). While you *could* replace the binding for the `tabbrowser` element by your own that inherits from the original binding, the better solution to your problem would be overlaying the browser window to run your code in its context. That code would then modify the `tabbrowser` instance of the window. So in `chrome.manifest` you would write:

```
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://dragdrop/content/browserOverlay.xul
```

And in `browserOverlay.xul`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<overlay id="ondrop-overlay"
         xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"> 
  <script type="application/x-javascript" src="browserOverlay.js"/>
</overlay>
```

And finally, `browserOverlay.js` would look like this:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(event)
{
  var browser = window.getBrowser();

  // Replace browser.onDrop method by own function but keep the original so that it
  // can be called later.
  var origOnDrop = browser.onDrop;
  browser.onDrop = function(aEvent, aXferData, aDragSession)
  {
    if (...)
    {
      // Your own processing of the call (start a search)
      ...
    }
    else
    {
      // Let the original function handle the call
      origOnDrop.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
});
```

Note that the code above avoids using global variables, all variables are declared inside a function. This is generally a good course of action because you are running in the context of the browser window - any global variables are shared with the browser's own code and the code of other extensions also running in this context. Two pieces of code choosing the same name for their global variable could lead to nasty issues, not using any global variables is the best way to avoid this.

---

**Edit**: You were apparently looking at outdated code (Gecko 1.8 branch). The current code has no `onDrop` method but rather [a proper event handler](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/e794cef56df6/browser/base/content/tabbrowser.xml#l3529) on the tab container element. You cannot replace an event handler - but you also don't need to because it will not do anything if the text dragged isn't a link. So you can simply add your own event handler that will handle this case.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(event)
{
  var browser = window.getBrowser();
  browser.tabContainer.addEventListener("drop", function(event)
  {
    if (...)
    {
      // This is a search string, do something with it
      ...
      // Indicate that we processed the event
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }, false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer sir, but can you help me a bit more? browser.onDrop seems is null. Where is tabbrowser's onDrop? Thanks again :)

Comment: So much about linking to outdated code ;). See update to my answer.

Comment: One little question about this, do you know why event.stopPropagation() is not working? I attempted stopImmediatePropagation, preventDefault and returning false but non of them was successful for me :( It is a firefox bug I think, is't it? (I promise I will not ask my other questions on this page, but I think this is still relevant to this)

Comment: It will not stop default Firefox behavior. This is what I want to do finally: http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1645141 (I will not ask you how I can get default search engine URL from Firefox, I will figure out that somehow or I will ask another question, but if you like, please say that too :D I guess I must retrieve browser.search.defaultenginename with Services.prefs.getBoolPref and do something with it)

Comment: @EbrahimByagowi: I assumed that you want to extend browser's defautl behavior, not replace it. Stopping propagation is pointless - the two event handlers are on the same level. You would have to attach your handler a level higher (the browser itself) and set the "capture" parameter to `true`. But then you would also have to replicate browser's behavior - that would quickly get complicated.